# How can I print schema / table definitions in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, schema

How can I print out the schema of all tables using sqlalchemy?

This is how I do it using SQLite3: I run an SQL to print out the schema of all tables in the database:

```py
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect("example.db")
cur = conn.cursor()

rs = cur.execute(
    """
    SELECT name, sql FROM sqlite_master
    WHERE type='table'
    ORDER BY name;
    """)

for name, schema, *args in rs:
    print(name)
    print(schema)
    print()
```

With output that can look like this:

```
albums
CREATE TABLE "albums"
(
    [AlbumId] INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,
    [Title] NVARCHAR(160)  NOT NULL,
    [ArtistId] INTEGER  NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY ([ArtistId]) REFERENCES "artists" ([ArtistId]) 
        ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
)

artists
CREATE TABLE "artists"
(
    [ArtistId] INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,
    [Name] NVARCHAR(120)
)
```

Is there a way to do it with pure `sqlalchemy` api calls, something better than this?

```py
metadata = sqlalchemy.MetaData()
metadata.reflect(engine)
insp = sqlalchemy.inspect(engine)

for table_name in metadata.tables:
    print(table_name)
    for column in insp.get_columns(table_name):
        for name,value in column.items():
            print('  ', end='')
            if value:
                field = name if value in [True, 'auto'] else value 
                print(field, end=' ')
        print()
```

Output:

```
albums
  AlbumId   INTEGER       autoincrement   primary_key 
  Title   NVARCHAR(160)       autoincrement   
  ArtistId   INTEGER       autoincrement   

artists
  ArtistId   INTEGER       autoincrement   primary_key 
  Name   NVARCHAR(120)   nullable     autoincrement
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This bit in the SQLAlchemy docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/faq/metadata_schema.html#how-can-i-get-the-create-table-drop-table-output-as-a-string) may help: they suggest doing this:

```
def dump(sql, *multiparams, **params):
    print(sql.compile(dialect=engine.dialect))
engine = create_engine('postgresql://', strategy='mock', executor=dump)
metadata.create_all(engine, checkfirst=False)
```